# 2 columns layout in css (ordering items)

Tags: css, layout

Is there any way to show 2 columns layout with this html code using only css? (`column1` class should be in first column, and `column2` class in the second one)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column1">1a</div>
    <div class="column2">1b</div>
    <div class="column2">2b<br>zz</div>
    <div class="column1">2a</div>
    <div class="column2">3b</div>
    <div class="column2">4b</div>
    <div class="column2">5b</div>
    <div class="column1">3a</div>
    <div class="column1">4a</div>
</div>
```

The result I expect:

```
1a 1b
2a 2b
3a zz
4a 3b
   4b
   5b
```

Comment: What did you try?  Float or display ? Did you notice html code and expected result do not match ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I would like to use display

Comment: @KevinHernandez, you can see there is two classes: column1 and column2, and items are not ordered.

Comment: Give a try to display:grid and grid-column: x ;

Comment: @G-Cyr, I think `display: grid` is not valid because my 'cells' can have different heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float` seems the best option here if you manage the [Block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

example :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div div {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px;/* see me */
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 1.4em; /* because of that 2 lines element , to hide the gap */
  background: lightblue;/* see me too */
}

.column1:first-child {
  float: left; /* let another float stand aside */
}

.column2 {
  float: right;
  clear: right;/* pile us to the far right */
}

div div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightgreen;/* see me different */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">1a</div>
  <div class="column2">1b</div>
  <div class="column2">2b<br>zz</div>
  <div class="column1">2a</div>
  <div class="column2">3b</div>
  <div class="column2">4b</div>
  <div class="column2">5b</div>
  <div class="column1">3a</div>
  <div class="column1">4a</div>
</div>
```

It matches your expected layout here, but will it also with real content ?

Comment: It seems very well but if I apply `margin-top: 10px` to all items, it does not work with the first one: https://jsfiddle.net/wv30zu26/

Comment: @Amparo as i wrote : *It matches your expected layout here, but will it also with real content ?* from your bits of code we can manage something alike, in real , you will probably need grid + placement for each single elements. CSS as limits how it can deal with natural flow. For your example, you need again to deal with the block formatting context : https://jsfiddle.net/8y0e5n4w/ remenber the first element floats !

Comment: i would even say, do not forget about floatting elements : https://jsfiddle.net/8y0e5n4w/1/ @Amparo ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this would be to float the classes of `.column1` and `.column2` like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.column2 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">1a</div>
  <div class="column2">1a</div>
  <div class="column1">2b</div>
  <div class="column1">3a</div>
  <div class="column2">2b</div>
  <div class="column2">3b</div>
  <div class="column2">4b</div>
  <div class="column1">4a</div>
  <div class="column1">5a</div>
</div>
```

You could also maybe simplify this by having only two inner divs representing each column like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your result is not valid. Please, see my example above. Thanks anyway

Comment: You want the columns to be closer together?

Comment: Your css does not order the cells, please see my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same thing using minimal code via using flex. Just add following code to your CSS.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Explanation :- You add display type flex to the container, so all the elements will be arranged next to each other inside this div.

Now when you give width of 50% to internal divs and give flex-wrap: wrap to the container, it ensures that only 2 divs are next to each other since there is no space left to accommodate more.

Alternatively if you want the items closer to each other you can reduce the width of the outer container.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 10%;
}

.container div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

This would be closer to what you are expecting.

Comment: Please, see my example. Ordering is important (without changing html code)

Comment: I don't see any element with 1b value or 2a value in the question. Can you please recheck the markup ? I give you a quick solution after you update the corrected markup.

Comment: you are right, there was any error. Now, my example is fixed.

Comment: "<div class="column2">2b<br>zz</div>" This zz is intentional or by mistake ? Is this the markup that you have to mandatorily work with ?

Comment: Yes, `zz` is correct. it is to see that the cells can have several heights

Comment: So, you want ordering of elements to happen based on class type, Irrespective of the markup that you give. I don't think that would be possible via a pure CSS solution. Also, most of times we prefer our markup to be straightforward in order to avoid hacky code.